# Run-time error 619 The control could not be found by id

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I've written following code in VBA.

When go in the for...next loop for the orders, that report contains data it works well, but for the orders, that don't contain data VBA gives the message:

> Run-time error '619': The control could not be found by id.
>
> [image: SAP GUI Run-time error '619': The control could not be found by id.]

When I start to execute macro form the line with the empty order, macro goes to the line1, but if the next order doesn't have the data, macro stops working.

It stops on this line:

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/shellcont/shell/shellcont[2]/shell").hierarchyHeaderWidth = 453
```

Could you help?

Code:

```
Sub sales_status_kpi()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    SheetSrc = "Input data"

    On Error Resume Next
    
    If Not IsObject(SAPApplication) Then
        Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Sub
        Set SAPApplication = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
        Set Connection = SAPApplication.Children(0)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox ("Please, open SAP!")
            
            Exit Sub
        Else
            
        End If
    End If

    If Not IsObject(session) Then
        Set session = Connection.Children(0)
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0
 
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01") / 1.5)
    
    Dim i As Double
    Dim last_row As Double
    
    last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 11 To last_row
    session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/Ns_alr_87013019"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txt$6-KOKRS").Text = "EU01"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxt_6ORDGRP-LOW").Text = Cells(i, 1)
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxt_6ORDGRP-LOW").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxt_6ORDGRP-LOW").caretPosition = 6
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
On Error GoTo line1
session.findById("wnd[0]/shellcont/shell/shellcont[2]/shell").hierarchyHeaderWidth = 453
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[62,8]").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[62,8]").caretPosition = 9
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 2
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/lbl[1,2]").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/lbl[1,2]").caretPosition = 4
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 2
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").currentCellColumn = "BELNR"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").selectedRows = "0"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").contextMenu
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").selectContextMenuItem "&XXL"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/cmbG_LISTBOX").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/cmbG_LISTBOX").Key = "31"
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
Dim path As String
path = Cells(2, 6)
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = path
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = Cells(i, 1).Value & ".XLSX"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").caretPosition = 10
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
Cells(i, 2) = "File generated"
line1:
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use error handling, for example:

```
On Error Resume Next
session.findById("wnd[0]/shellcont/shell/shellcont[2]/shell").hierarchyHeaderWidth = 453
```

Comment: In that case, click the checkmark on the left to indicate it helped you.

Comment: Sorry for that. Beginner here